How can I conduct an experiment to find that RDMA throughput decreases as the number of QPS increases?
My experimental environment is two machines equipped with one Mellanox CX-5, directly connected.
If I want to get this result graph, how do I conduct my experiment? I have tried the ib_read/write_bw/lat of perftest. Is it necessary to write C++ code to achieve multi-threaded RDMA communication at the same time to get?
I want to get a graph of how RDMA throughput declines as the number of QPS increases

Please check out the following repositories that support multithreading RDMA:

https://github.com/efficient/rdma_bench (sender-scalability especially)
https://github.com/madsys-dev/smart


Thank you for your answer. I am sorry that I cannot meet the test conditions required by this GitHub project. If it really takes that many machines to do it, I'll have to find another way.

@user24969355 I'm not sure if you misunderstand the test condition. For sender-scalability, "clients" or "servers" are threads instead of physical servers.

Thank you very much for the tip. I found that the test in a paper was quite in line with my expectations, and it was tested using perftest benchmark. It says something about connecting the two NICs directly. Each machine is set up with 16 threads and each thread performs a 512B send operation. The aggregate throughput is then obtained using the standard perftest benchmark when the number of QPs is increased from 128 to 10k. How do I do the test?

@user24969355 It seems perftest doesn't support multithreading. So I'm guessing he might be using multiple parallel perftest processes. Which paper is that by the way?

The paper is "SRNIC: A Scalable Architecture for RDMA NICs". In Section 6.
